# Peskin and Schroeder, Feynman diagram for the Yukawa potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, identical-particles

On page 121 of Peskin and Schroeder, second paragraph, about fermion+fermion $\rightarrow$ fermion+fermion scattering, the book says:

> "if the two interacting particles are distinguishable, only the first diagram in 4.119 contributes."

Here is 4.119, can someone help me by explaining why the 2nd one doesn't contribute? In the derivation before, Peskin and Schroeder don't mention anything about distinguishable or identical particles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contribute because you know in advance that $p^{\prime}$ is particle 1's momentum, and $k^{\prime}$ is particle 2's momentum, because they are distinguishable.  You only get the extra diagram because you can't know which particle is which in the final state in the indistinguishable case.

Comment: But why are momentum separately conserved though? Also Peskin and Schroeder's derivation leading up to 4.119 seems watertight to me, I'm confused as to which step is causing problems here.

Comment: @Simplyorange: the second diagram only comes about because you have to antisymmetrize the wavefunction due to indistinguishability, because you can't tell which particle is in which "out" state.  If they are distinguishable, you know which particle is in which state, and you only have one diagram.

Comment: i think you meant "indistinguishable case" in your last sentence.

Comment: @Vangi fixed, thank you